# Traveling with BlackDiamond Jetforce avalanche rescue backpack

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I am traveling with a Blackdiamond Halo Jetforce 28 avalanche rescue backpack. The backpack airbag is inflated through a lithium ion battery powered fan (no gas canister), with a lithium battery pack of 43.2Wh.
I would like to know if it should go with my backpack as cabin or check-in luggage, and if I should get an in-advance permission from the airline.

Comment: It would help to know if there was a particular route/airline you were travelling. There are general rules for these things but there are also specific rules per country and airline. As I understand the device it's not an explosive airbag but it probably comes close in many peoples minds -- it's the sort of thing you'd probably be better having explicit clearance in advance for. But, maybe I'm wrong and it's more common than I think it is.

Comment: In the USA, most airlines have recently started to decline to take *anything* with a medium or larger lithium battery, no matter if it's carry-on or checked luggage. That might be similar in other countrys. I recommend you contact your airline to make sure you can take it *at all*

Answer (score 2):

United airlines:  No
https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/baggage/dangerous.aspx

American airlines:  I find no mention, presumably ok.

Delta airlines:  The gas cylinder inflated ones are ok, no mention of the battery ones.  Presumably ok.

Answer (score 2):

KLM okay, up to 100 Wh no approval needed. But the battery must be removed!

On the [special baggage](https://www.klm.nl/en/information/baggage/special-baggage#sports-equipment) page of KLM:

> You're allowed to bring an avalanche rescue backpack instead of a piece of hand or checked baggage or to pack it in your suitcase. Please be aware that you always need to make a reservation to transport this.

> Avalanche rescue backpacks with an explosive trigger mechanism are never allowed in your baggage.

About [the batteries](https://www.klm.nl/en/information/baggage/restricted-items-hand-baggage) with KLM

> You’re allowed to bring 15 electronic devices with a lithium battery up to 100 Wh, and 20 spare lithium batteries or power banks up to 100 Wh. If you want to bring a lithium battery up to 160 Wh with you in your hand baggage, either in a device or as a spare, you need to request permission. Batteries larger than 160 Wh are never allowed. Devices and batteries should not be damaged, defective, or recalled.

Comment: Can you add a link to where you found this information and put the particular part about batteries as a blockquote?

Comment: I am a pilot at KLM. It is in our manual FSSM. So I can not send you a link, you have to believe me. Best I can do is copy-paste that part:

Comment: Avalanche rescue backpack, one per person, containing cartridges
of compressed gas in division 2.2 (non-flammable gas). May also be
equipped with a pyrotechnic trigger mechanism, containing no more
than 200 mg net of explosives in division 1.4S. The backpack must be
packed in such a manner that it cannot be accidentally activated. The
airbags within the backpacks must be fitted with pressure relief
valves.
Note: The carriage of avalanche rescue backpacks containing an
explosive (1.4S) trigger mechanism to/from/through or within the
USA is not authorized.

Comment: And battery part: DEVICES AND EQUIPMENT CONTAINING LITHIUM METAL BATTERIES NOT EXCEEDING 2
GRAM OF LITHIUM, OR LITHIUM ION BATTERIES NOT EXCEEDING 100 Wh.

Baggage equipped with a removable lithium battery (metal
or ion), other than button cells: the battery must be removable.
If offered as checked baggage (desk checked or gate
checked), the battery must be removed and carried in the cabin.

Baggage equipped with a non-removable lithium battery
are forbidden both as checked or carry-on baggage.

Comment: Awesome @Flying Dutchman . I think you should add that to your original answer: "it's in our FSSM (what does FSSM mean?) manual. 
And add the parts from the manual as blockquote's, not as a comment.

Comment: FSSM is Flight Safety and Security Manual.

Comment: Here’s a link to official KLM site with some info for passengers. Reservation should be made in advance: https://www.klm.nl/en/information/baggage/special-baggage#sports-equipment

Comment: In the link you provided, it says "Avalanche rescue backpacks with an explosive trigger mechanism are never allowed in your baggage."
But in your FSSM text, it says you are allowed to bring it: "May also be equipped with a pyrotechnic trigger mechanism, containing no more than 200 mg net of explosives in division 1.4S"
Probably unique to pilots?

Comment: Sharp! I am trying to find out… As a pilot, I know I can accept it, if it would somehow “pop-up” in the cabin, under the provisions in our FSSM. But the policy on the website is indeed contradictory… If I find out more, I’ll let you know… 

Comment: @FlyingDutchman please [edit] your answer to include the link, all that quoted text, and any followups. That will make it much easier for others to find because not everybody reads the comments.

Comment: @JorenVandamme Note that what is allowed in baggage and what is allowed to be carried on differ--some things are only legal in baggage, some things are only legal carried on.